# Android: Open a browser window without showing the address bar

Tags: android, browser

I am developing a small android application. When the user hasn't signed up, he will see a website, by calling the browser like this:

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
    Uri.parse("http://OUR WEBSITE.tld/register/?id=" + user_id));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

The only issue I face, is that the user will see the url, and be able visit other websites. I want him to return to the app, when the registration is done.

I also do not want to save history from this session.

I am thinking about how to integrate the browser into the app, but I assume there is an easier way, that I may have missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use a web view in your app, and it will load the page only as per the url provided to it.
Url will not be visible to user by default.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you start an ActivityForResult(...)? This would solve your issue.

Ref:
[startActivityForResult(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)

Comment: How will we know that user is registered .

Comment: You have to find some way to pass that information back to the application. I'm not family with webkit enough to help you with that. But I think it is possible.